# Display .pdf from a link displayed in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I have an iOS app that displays blurbs of HTML grabbed from a database, and some of these blurbs contain a hyperlink to a .pdf hosted on the server. However, when I click the links that link to the .pdf, nothing happens. How would I have my app handle opening the .pdf and displaying it within a UIWebView? 
I am NOT looking for how to just load a .pdf into a web view, I know how to do that. But all of my searching only shows examples of loading a .pdf into a UIWebView via a NSURLRequest.

```
//I need this link to open a PDF!
    [_webView loadHTMLString:@"<a href='/Users/User/Desktop/test.pdf'>Click Me to Load a PDF!</a>" baseURL:nil];


/*  Not this!
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/User/Desktop/test.pdf"];
    NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [_webView loadRequest:req];
    */
```

Comment: whats the url of you pdf file? or you are trying to show it from app document directory.

Comment: Whatever the URL is listed as in the database it is pulled from

Answer (score 0):

You should set `baseURL` argument correctly to your server's URL.

For example, if you can access a pdf in a browser with `http://example.com/path/a.pdf` and `href="path/a.pdf"` then `baseURL` should be `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"]`.